# Insert data from a JsonArray using updateWithParms in vertx

Tags: sql, prepared-statement, vert.x

Is is possible to use updatewithparms() in vertx postgres client to insert data to the using an json array. I tried the following with out any success.

```
String  INSERT_QUERY="INSERT INTO testDb (rid , aid , created_at, expiry_time, strings , strings) VALUES"

private JsonArray preparedParameters(){
    //JsonArray params = new JsonArray();
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    return new JsonArray()
            .add(device.getRecordId().toString())
            .add( device.getAccountId())
            .add(dateTimeFormat.format(device.getCreatedAt()))
            .add(dateTimeFormat.format(device.getExpiresAt()))
            .add( device.getEnrollmentId())
            .add(device.getHashedEnrollmentId());
}
```

Then I call functions as follows.

```
try (SQLConnection connection = connectionResult.result()) {
        connection.updateWithParams(INSERT_QUERY,preparedParameters() ,queryRes -> {
            if (queryRes.succeeded()) {
                booleanFuture.complete(true);
            } else {
                booleanFuture.complete(false);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {

        booleanFuture.complete(false);
    }
```

I receive the following error.

```
The query contains 0 parameters but you gave it 6 ("sda","sda",2018-01-22 20:23:26,2018-02-21 20:23:26,"sda","sda")
```

com.github.mauricio.async.db.exceptions.InsufficientParametersException: The query contains 0 parameters but you gave it 6 ("sda","sda",2018-01-22 20:23:26,2018-02-21 20:23:26,"sda","sda")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is not valid, it misses the parameters.

```
String  INSERT_QUERY="INSERT INTO testDb (rid , aid , created_at, expiry_time, strings , strings) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
```

See the [Prepared Statement Updates](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-sql-common/java/#_prepared_statement_updates) section of the Vert.x SQL doc.